# Add a task in a batch loop

Tags: batch, batch-file

I did a batch file

```
for %%a in ("*.txt") do ( xxxx )
```

And When I run it I get new files, I want to know how can I copy the new files into a shared folder. 
only new files even if they have the same extentions.
for exemple may I do something like

> If file is less than 5mb copy it to \Network ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `DO (IF NOT EXIST "C:\destination\%%~A" XCOPY /F /Y "%%~A" "C:\destination\")`... You might consider looking into [RoboCopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) though.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I copy files smaller than 5mb to \Network?

You can use [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) for this task:

```
forfiles /m *.txt /c "cmd /c if @fsize lss 5242880 echo copy @path \Network"
```

Remove the `echo` when you are happy with the command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) - Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. Batch processing.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.